# Teradata : using case statement in Where clause

Tags: case, teradata, where-clause

My question is about using case statement in where clause to check for date and assign values to columns. My sample code include.

```
select * from table
where 
column 1 > 10 and 
case when column 2 = 1 
  then 
    column 3<= 10 and column 4 between (1st day of prev month) and (prev month end) or column 5 = '8888-01-01' 
  else 
    column 4 between (1st day of this month) and (yesterday)
end ;
```

when I am running this code. I am getting 3706 syntax error:expected something in between  field and '='.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

A CASE statement will always return a value or NULL (if none of the conditions matches), so you can use it in your WHERE clause.  There are a couple ways to format your CASE statement:

**Format 1**

```
CASE 
WHEN <condition> THEN <some_expression> 
WHEN <another_condition> THEN <another_expression>
ELSE <final_expression> 
END

-- Example
CASE 
WHEN col1 = 10 THEN 'Y'
WHEN col1 = 20 THEN 'N'
ELSE 'N/A'
END
```

**Format 2**

```
CASE <expression>
WHEN <value> THEN <expression>
WHEN <another_value> THEN <another_expression>
ELSE <final_expression>
END

-- Example
CASE col1
WHEN 10 THEN 'Y'
WHEN 20 THEN 'N'
ELSE 'NA'
END
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your sample code, but it looks more like pseudo-code and will not work as-is.  Your CASE statement is not formatted properly and your column references like `column 1` will not work that way.  If your column is actually named `column 1`, then you need to put double-quotes around it:

`select * from table where "column 1" > 10`

Can you please describe a little more clearly what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to run my SQL code based on current date. if my current date is 1st day of the month it should return previous month data or else it should return current month till yesterday. based on this condition I need to assign upper and lower limit dates to my columns. I tried this using the case statement in where clause. I am getting 3706 syntax error. I am not sure if this happening because I am using 'between' in my case.

Answer (score 0):

A *CASE expression* can't be used to create some kind of dynamic conditions. Write it as a bunch of AND/OR conditons:

```
select * from table
where 
column 1 > 10 and 
 (
   ( column 2 = 1 and
     (column 3<= 10 and column 4 between (1st day of prev month) and (prev month end) or column 5 = '8888-01-01')
   )
  or  
    column 4 between (1st day of this month) and (yesterday)
 );
```

Double check the logic, the precedence of logical operators is

1. parenthesis
2. NOT
3. AND
4. OR